# How to implement operator+ in abstract base class

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, abstract-class

I want to implement an abstract Matrix (template) class and implement a lazy implementation first. Later on I want to implement a more performance oriented version of this class and want to use it in my whole project without changing everything.

The current problem is, that I am running in problems while implementing the +-operator.

The code below is one iteration, but i tried many different possibilities. But either I get an C2259 "Could not create instance of abstract class" like in the example below or I get runtime problems (Access violations while returning a reference or pointer).

I am sure that I am missing an easy and stupid point (again).

**AbstMatrix.cpp:**

```
#pragma once

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Matrix.hpp"

template<typename T>
class AbstMatrix // : public AddMultEnabled<AbstMatrix<T>>
{
    public:
        inline virtual size_t getNRows() const = 0;
        inline virtual size_t getNCols() const = 0;
        inline size_t getNEle() const { return this->getNCols() * this->getNRows(); }

        inline virtual T get(size_t iRow, size_t iCol) const = 0;
        inline virtual void set(size_t iRow, size_t iCol, T val) = 0;

        // Element wise addition
        virtual AbstMatrix<T>& operator+=(const AbstMatrix<T>& obj) {
            cout << "AM: op+=" << endl;
            if (this->getNRows() != obj->getNRows()
                || this->getNCols() != obj->getNCols()) {
                throw "Matricies unequal";
            }

            for (size_t i = 0; i < this->getNRows(); i++) {
                for (size_t j = 0; j < this->getNCols(); j++) {
                    this->set(i, j, this->get(i, j) + obj->get(i, j));
                }
            }
            return *this;
        }


      // Elementwise addition
      virtual AbstMatrix<T> operator+(const AbstMatrix<T>& obj) const {
        cout << "AM: op+" << endl;
        Matrix<T> retM(*this);
        return retM += obj;
      }
};
```

**Matrix.cpp:**

```
#pragma once

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include "AbstMatrix.hpp"

template<typename T>
class Matrix : public AbstMatrix<T>
{
  protected:
    size_t nRows;
    size_t nCols;
    size_t nEle;
    T* dat;
  public:
    Matrix(size_t nRows, size_t nCols, T defVal = 0) {
        this->nRows = nRows;
        this->nCols = nCols;
        this->nEle = nCols*nRows;
        this->dat = new T[this->getNEle()];
        std::fill_n(this->dat, this->getNEle(), defVal);
    }

    Matrix(const AbstMatrix& obj) {
        cout << "M: abst cpy:" << &obj << endl;
        this->nRows = obj.getNRows();
        this->nCols = obj.getNCols();
        this->nEle = obj.getNEle();
        this->dat = new T[this->getNEle()];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < this->getNRows(); i++) {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < this->getNCols(); j++) {
                this->set(i, j, obj.get(i, j));
            }
        }
    }

    Matrix & operator= (const AbstMatrix & obj) {
        this->nRows = obj.getNRows();
        this->nCols = obj.getNCols();
        this->nEle = obj.getNEle();
        this->dat = new T[this->getNEle()];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < this->getNRows(); i++) {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < this->getNCols(); j++) {
                this->set(i, j, obj.get(i, j));
            }
        }
    }

    ~Matrix() { if (this->dat) delete[] this->dat; }


    inline size_t getNRows() const { return this->nRows; }
    inline size_t getNCols() const { return this->nCols; }
    inline size_t getNEle() const { return this->nEle; }

    inline T get(size_t iRow, size_t iCol) const {
        cout << "M: get " << iRow << ", " << iCol << endl;
        return this->dat[this->getIdx(iRow, iCol)];
    }

    inline void set(size_t iRow, size_t iCol, T val) {
        cout << "M: set " << iRow << ", " << iCol << endl;
        this->dat[this->getIdx(iRow, iCol)] = val;
    }

    inline AbstMatrix* clone() const {
        cout << "M: clone " << endl;
        return new Matrix(*this);
    }

protected:
    size_t getIdx(size_t iCol, size_t iRow) const {
        cout << "M: getIdx " << iRow << ", " << iCol << ", "
            << (size_t) (this->getNCols() * iRow + iCol) << endl;
        return this->getNCols() * iRow + iCol;
    }
};
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Matrix.hpp"

int main()
{
    Matrix<float> a(5, 5);
    Matrix<float> b(5, 5);
    a + b;
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you a lot for your help!

[EDIT:] I fixed the (copy-paste) errors mentioned below. Matrix has now a copy and a move constructor. I added the following code at the bottom of AbstMatrix:

```
namespace detail {
    template <typename T>
    T AbstMatrix_ElemType(const AbstMatrix<T>&) { return T(); }
}

template <typename M1, typename M2>
auto operator+(M1 obj1, const M2& obj2)
-> std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_same<decltype(detail::AbstMatrix_ElemType(obj1)),
    decltype(detail::AbstMatrix_ElemType(obj2))>::value,
    M1> {
    return obj1 += obj2;
}

template <typename M1, typename M2>
auto operator*(M1 obj1, const M2& obj2)
-> std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_same<decltype(detail::AbstMatrix_ElemType(obj1)),
    decltype(detail::AbstMatrix_ElemType(obj2))>::value,
    M1> {
    return obj1 *= obj2;
}

// Mat multiplication
template <typename M1, typename M2>
auto mult(M1 obj1, const M2& obj2)
-> std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_same<decltype(detail::AbstMatrix_ElemType(obj1)),
    decltype(detail::AbstMatrix_ElemType(obj2))>::value,
    M1> {

    cout << "AM: mult" << endl;
    if (obj1.getNCols() != obj2.getNRows()) {
        throw("Matricies incompatible");
    }

    typedef decltype(detail::AbstMatrix_ElemType(obj1)) matValueType;

    M1 retM(obj1.getNRows(), obj2.getNCols());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < obj1.getNRows(); i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < obj2.getNCols(); j++) {
            matValueType tmp = 0;
            for (size_t x = 0; x < obj1.getNCols(); x++) {
                tmp += obj1.get(i, x) * obj2.get(x, j);
            }
            retM.set(i, j, tmp);
        }
    }
    return retM;
}
```

This works perfectly for me. I unfortunately still don't understand why this code works. I tried to read the doc at cppreference, but it just confused me. Do you have a easier source where I can understand the code?

Thanks a lot @aschepler!

Comment: Oops: your `Matrix<T>` does not define a copy constructor or copy assignment operator, violating the Rule Of Three.  (The functions taking `AbstMatrix` will NOT be used for this purpose.)  Also, you use `obj->` in your `AbstMatrix<T>::operator+=`, although `obj` is not a pointer.

Comment: Also, uses of `AbstMatrix` must be `AbstMatrix<T>` within the scope of `Matrix<T>`.  The injected class name of a dependent base class is not found by unqualified name lookup.  (MSVC gets this wrong and allows just `AbstMatrix`, but other compilers won't.)

Comment: Since `AbstMatrix_ElemType` is only used inside `decltype`, it doesn't actually need a definition.  `mult` can take `obj1` by const reference, since it neither modifies nor stores `obj1` (unlike the two operators).  The `enable_if` fails to instantiate if either object doesn't inherit `AbstMatrix` or if the two matrices have different element types, which drops the template from overload resolution.

Comment: Thank you.
Now I have got a new annoying problem:
I want to include my AbstMatrix.hpp into an other class and I get compiling errors in Matrix.hpp. (I really just included it somewhere else.)
They are hpp files since I have to code all the stuff for the templates in one file. But I think this does not work in combination with pragma once...
I get errors C2143 and C4430 like if it does not know the class. But if I remove the include of AbstMatrix in the other class, Matrix is fine...
Do you encountered a problem like this? Does it come with your functions?

Comment: Do you still have a circular include? Note AbstMatrix.hpp does not need to include Matrix.hpp.  If that's not it, you may need to ask a new question.

Comment: I think you should write my programs from now on... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  // Elementwise addition
  virtual AbstMatrix<T> operator+(const AbstMatrix<T>& obj) const {
    cout << "AM: op+" << endl;
    Matrix<T> retM(*this);
    return retM += obj;
  }
```

You cannot use an abstract class such as `AbstMatrix<T>` as a return type, since that involves creating an object of exactly that type.  Also, your `operator+` implementation relies on a specific subclass `Matrix<T>`.  Generally a base class should not know anything about its derived classes (unless you're using CRTP).

Instead, you can define an `operator+` template outside the class that acts on any two objects that inherit the same specialization of `AbstMatrix`, and returns the LHS type:

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail {
    template <typename T>
    T AbstMatrix_ElemType(const AbstMatrix<T>&);
}

template <typename M1, typename M2>
auto operator+(M1 obj1, const M2& obj2)
-> std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_same<decltype(detail::AbstMatrix_ElemType(obj1)),
                 decltype(detail::AbstMatrix_ElemTYpe(obj2))>::value,
    M1>
{ return obj1 += obj2; }
```

Comment: I'm unable to run your example because all that enable_if stuff is new to me. But if it works it should be ab possible solution to my problem :-).
As far is I understand does the whole structure enable_if... belong into the template parameters? 
When I try to compile your code, just copy pasted below the class defenition and removed my operator+, I get "Type AbstMatrix<T> has no overloaded operator "->" " with all the calls to this->.

Comment: OK I saw now your comment below my code. Now It runs, but isn't Matrix(const AbstMatrix& obj) usable my copy constructor? I removed it to shrink it for the post here.
I will try it with my copy constructor.

Comment: This is the solution to my problem. Thank you a lot. My response is in the edit of the original post because I wanted to share the final code

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> virtual AbstMatrix<T> operator+(const AbstMatrix<T>& obj) const {
>         cout << "AM: op+" << endl;
>         Matrix<T> retM(*this);
>         return retM += obj;
>       }
> ```

You cannot write such an operator that returns an abstract class object. Simply put, your operator says *my method returns an instance of type AbstMatrix*, but such an instance cannot exist for an abstract class. You can only have actual instances of derived, concrete (non-abstract) classes, and hold on them a *reference* (`AbstMatrix<T>&`) or a *pointer* (`AbstMatrix<T>*`).

You are actually creating an instance of the derived type `Matrix<T>` but to match the function's prototype, the `return` statement is forced to convert it to an `AbstMatrix<T>` instance (a mechanism called object slicing; it has to create an instance of `AbstMatrix<T>` and invoke the copy constructor). Since it cannot create such an instance, a compile error occurs.

At best you can make your `operator+` to return a `Matrix<T>` object. But then the whole idea of having an abstract base class, that depends so strictly on one and only one of its derived classes, is not a good design idea. May be you should re-think the design and drop the idea of an abstract matrix class, bu only make it a class template.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Thats what I am thinking at the moment too, because it's becoming a mess. If one of the proposed solutions don't work, I will go for a lame and boring design...

Answer (score 0):

Abstract interfaces used like this are not suitable for value-semantic computing.

You cannot return an instance of an abstract class.  Actual instances -- values -- are of fixed storage size and type in C++.  Derives instances of abstract interfaces won't "fit".

There are a few ways around this.  One way is to implement your own polymorphism.

Start with `template<class T>class AbstMatrix` like you have.  Get rid of `operator`s -- **only** expose pure virtual methods.  Virtual operators "work", but are awkward to use, so do not bother.  Include `virtual std::unique_ptr<AbstMatrix>clone()const=0`  Consider eliminating other virtual methods; only include the ones you need.  See below.  You'll want `at(x,y)`, `clone()`, `increment_by(AbstMatrix)`, `mult_by(AbstMatrix)`, etc.

Next write `Matrix<T>`.  This does not inherit from `AbstMatrix<T>`, but instead *owns* a `std::unique_ptr<AbstMatrix<T>> pImpl;`.  It can be construxted from a `unique_ptr<AbstMatrix<T>>` as well.  It can be "empty"; its methods ahould not assume `pImpl` is non-null.

This `Matrix<T>` type implements `operator+=`, `operator+`, `operator=`, `Matrix(Matris const&)`, `Matrix(Matris&&)=default`, etc.  Its job is to be a *value semantics type* that is polymorphic because its behaviour is determined by the abstract class it owns in a unique ptr.

This lets you have a polymorphic value type.

Now your implementations inherit from `AbstMatrix<T>` and can be stored in a `Matrix<T>`.

Comment: But wouldn't it then easier to introduce an Interface which declares all the needed functions and have a Matrix-type which declares all the functions as base function?

The problem is that if I implement my base class like in my code above I have unneeded attributes if I want to do a Matrix type with a non dynamicaly allocated array and/or I have to reimplement all the reusable functions...